# My onEdit function is being triggered and I have no idea why

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My problem:

- Whenever I insert a row into my sheet anywhere below row 6, the script below runs.
- The things is... I have 2 sections below that are basically identical, but only section 1 is ever triggered when I insert a new row. Even if I remove section 1 completely, section 2 is never triggered by inserting a new row anywhere below row 6.
- Why is section 1 triggered by inserting a new row and not section 2? What's the difference? This did not used to happen - neither script would be triggered by inserting a new row, which I assumed was because the below if-statements were never satisfied.
- How can I have it so that when I insert a new row it does not trigger the below sections?

  ```
    function onEdit(e) {

      //This IF statement ensures that this onEdit macro only runs when columns 2-5, from row 5 and below is edited:
      if (
        e.source.getSheetName() == "Today" &&
        e.range.columnStart >= 2 &&
        e.range.columnEnd <= 5 &&
        e.range.rowStart >= 5  
      ) { 

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var Today = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today");  
      var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue()    //This variable is used in If statement below, to ensure the macro runs when the checkbox is checked.
      var Task_cellRow = e.range.rowStart      //This variable is used to determine which row to edit.

      // Section 1 - THIS SCRIPT IS TRIGGERED WHEN I INSERT A ROW BELOW ROW 6
      if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
        if (checkboxtest == true) {
        }else if(checkboxtest == false){
          //This script is to show if the above if-statements were triggered (they are)
          Today.getRange('A2').setValue("column 3 script was triggered");
        }
      }

      //Section 2 - THIS SCRIPT IS NOT TRIGGERED WHEN I INSERT A ROW BELOW ROW 6..... But as far as I can tell it is almost identical to the above.
      if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) {
        if (checkboxtest == true) {
        }else if(checkboxtest == false){
          //This script is to show if the above if-statements were triggered (they are not)
          Today.getRange('A3').setValue("column 4 script was triggered");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish because it's hard to tell what you want from your current explanation and script.  It looks like you may not fully understand what e.range.columnEnd is.

Comment: The questions needs more details regarding the question on the second bullet. In order to better understand what is happening you might find helpful to log the event object.

Comment: I don't want Section 1 OR Section 2 of my script to be triggered when I insert a new row. Section 2  works exactly as I want (that is, it is not triggered when I insert a new row), but Section 1 DOES get triggered when I insert a new row. I am trying to understand why that's the case when both sections seem relatively identical to me - and I ultimately want to get Section 1 to stop being triggered when I insert a new row.

Comment: Inserting of a row never fires the onEdit trigger. Maybe you mean copy-pasting data into a row?  Or in a single cell of a column? Please explain more in detail.

Comment: Also, your sections check either the inserted value is `true` or `false`. Is it intended? Is the data you are pastin a (single) checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

The only restriction that you have on row is that e.range.rowStart has to be greater that 4